# Sum up counts in a data.frame grouped by multiple variables

Tags: r, data-wrangling

This is a snippet of the dataset I am currently working on:

```
> sample
    name sex count
1  Maria   f    97
2 Thomas   m    12
3  Maria   m     5
4  Maria   f    97
5 Thomas   m     8
6  Maria   m     4
```

I want to sum up the counts grouped by `name` and `sex` to finally get this data.frame:

```
> result
    Maria Thomas
f   194      0
m     9     20
```

I wrote a simple loop to iterate over the rows and sum up the counts:

```
result <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=2)
colnames(result) <- unique(sample$name)
rownames(result) <- unique(sample$sex)

for (i in 1:nrow(sample)) {
    sex <- as.character(sample[i,"sex"])
    name <- sample[i,"name"]
    count <- sample[i,"count"]

    result[sex, name] <- result[sex, name] + count
}
```

Is it suitable to do it this way? Are there any other ways to do it in a more elegant / shorter fashion?

Edit:

I already tried it with `aggregate`, but the output is in a different format:

```
> aggregate(sample$count,by=list(sample$name,sample$sex),sum)
  Group.1 Group.2   x
1   Maria       m   9
2  Thomas       m  20
3   Maria       w 194
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `xtabs` function! Here's how I did it using your example data:

```
# Create example data...
name <- c("Maria", "Thomas", "Maria", "Maria", "Thomas", "Maria")
sex <- c("f", "m", "m", "f", "m", "m")
count <- c(97, 12, 5, 97, 8, 4)
data <- data.frame("name"=name, "sex"=sex, "count"=count)

# Create table...
xtabs(formula=count~name + sex, data=data)
```

which gives the following output:

```
        sex
name       f   m
Maria    194   9
Thomas     0  20
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` is also another option you can explore. Working with data.tables is more efficient when you do certain operations on your table. Its simple to use as well.

```
require(data.table) 
DT <- data.table(data) 
DT[ , .(Totalcount = sum(count)), by = .(name,sex)]
```

*output*

```
     name sex Totalcount
1:  Maria   f        194
2: Thomas   m         20
3:  Maria   m          9
```